# How do I enable the done key and the return key in ipad objective c

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Is it possible to enable or show both the "return" and "done" button on the ipad keyboard?  If so, How or how to work around?

I have a UITextField that is multi-line and want to add a done button to the key board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think the keyboard can display both without augmenting the layout manually - Additionally this is not app store safe.

I have done this before by hooking the

-`(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)_tf`

In the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html). Although there might be a better keyboard based event to use. If your interested i will post the code.

On this event, A small toolbar appeared flush with the top of the keyboard containing next, previous and Done.

I delegated the button events from the toolbar back to the ViewController that was responsible for the TextField

Comment: So I need to provide my own "Done" button? Like by adding a toolbar?

Comment: Yes, iOS3.2 supports a keyboard toolbar view

Comment: Didn't even know that it was supported, perhaps its even easier than i have illustrated then, Justin more info/link?

Comment: Yeah please provide a link to this keyboard toolbar view. Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: Justin is talking about the same thing as i am, though I have done it from scratch.